# Images won't change when clearly defined

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having this problem all my code looks correct to me, but when I run the submit() function it doesn't change the image based on the box selected. Please help if you can, would gladly appreciate any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Computer System Order</title>
  <script>
    var imgArray = new Array(9);
    var index = 0;

    function submit() {
      if (document.ComputerForm.computerCase[0].checked) {
        alert("Box one selected");
        document.ComputerForm.caseimg.src = imgArray[0].src;

      } else if (document.ComputerForm.computerCase[1].checked) {
        alert("Box two selected");
        document.ComputerForm.caseimg.src = imgArray[1].src;
      } else {
        alert("Box three selected");
        document.ComputerForm.caseimg.src = imgArray[2].src;
      }
    }

    function startup() {
      imgArray[0] = new Image;
      imgArray[0].src = imgArray[0].alt = "desktopcase.jpg";
      imgArray[1] = new Image;
      imgArray[1].src = imgArray[1].alt = "minidesktop.jpg";
      imgArray[2] = new Image;
      imgArray[2].src = imgArray[2].alt = "fulltower.jpg";
      imgArray[3] = new Image;
      imgArray[3].src = imgArray[3].alt = "17monitor.jpg";
      imgArray[4] = new Image;
      imgArray[4].src = imgArray[4].src = "19monitor.jpg";
      imgArray[5] = new Image;
      imgArray[5].src = imgArray[5].src = "21monitor.jpg";
      imgArray[6] = new Image;
      imgArray[6].src = imgArray[6].src = "inkprinter.jpg";
      imgArray[7] = new Image;
      imgArray[7].src = imgArray[7].src = "laserprinter.jpg";
      imgArray[8] = new Image;
      imgArray[8].src = imgArray[8].src = "colorlaserprinter.jpg";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="startup()">
  <form name="ComputerForm">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>
            <font face="Courier New">
      <br>
      <br>
            <b>Computer Case Style:</b><br><input name="computerCase" type="radio">Desktop Case ($500.00)<br>
            <input name="computerCase" type="radio">Mini-Tower ($600.00)<br>
            <input name="computerCase" type="radio">Full Tower Case ($700.00)<br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Computer Monitor:</b><br><input name="monitor" type="radio">17" LCD Flat Screen ($250.00)<br>
            <input name="monitor" type="radio">19" LCD Flat Screen ($300.00)<br>
            <input name="monitor" type="radio">21" LCD Flat Screen ($350.00)<br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Computer Printer:</b><br><input name="printer" type="radio">Inkjet Printer ($100.00)<br>
            <input name="printer" type="radio">Laser Printer ($250.00)<br>
            <input name="printer" type="radio">Color Laser Printer ($350.00)<br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="submit()">
           </font>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td name="tableOne">
          <img name="caseimg" alt="caseimg" width="125" height="125" src="desktopcase.jpg">
          <br>
          <img name="monitorimg" alt="monitoring" width="125" height="125" src="17monitor.jpg">
          <br>
          <img name="printerimg" alt="printerimg" width="125" height="125" src="inkprinter.jpg">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img name="caseimg" alt="caseimg" width="125" height="125" src="desktopcase.jpg">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You must be coming from another computer language. JavaScript is not a declarative language. You do not have to initialize your variables and objects. I.E. The array and the image. You can do this in far less code. If you give me a few minute I can show you some code.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript although you can initialize an Array the way that you did it is easier and more common to create the variable and then just place the values in the square brackets if you know what they are going to be.

```
var imgArray = ["desktopcase.jpg","minidesktop.jpg","fulltower.jpg","17monitor.jpg","19monitor.jpg","21monitor.jpg","inkprinter.jpg","laserprinter.jpg","colorlaserprinter.jpg"];
```

I used jQuery to grab all of the radio buttons, places a onClick event listener on them, and then the function that will perform that actions.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', radioIptFunc);
```

And now the fun part.

```
function radioIptFunc(){
            var fileReg = /(\w*)/, //regular expression to get the file name without the extension from the imgArray array.
                gotVal = this.value, // get the radio input value.
                fileName = '', // sets up a variable to store the file name
                foundi = '', // sets up a variable to store found image file name from the array filter.
                nameAtr = this.name;  // gets the name from the clicked radio button.

                // this is the array filter that looks to see if the selected radio buttons value is in the array. the result is stored in the returned filter array (foundi).
                foundi = imgArray.filter(function( val ){
                    fileName = val.match(fileReg)[0];
                    return fileName === gotVal;
                });

            // switch statement that matches the selected product to the image/s that are to be changed.
            switch(nameAtr ){
                case 'computerCase':
                    $('[name="caseimg"]').attr('src', foundi);
                    $('[name="caseimg"]').attr('alt', gotVal);
                    break;
                case 'monitor':
                    $('[name="monitorimg"]').attr('src', foundi);
                    $('[name="monitorimg"]').attr('alt', gotVal);
                    break;
                case 'printer':
                    $('[name="printerimg"]').attr('src', foundi);
                    $('[name="printerimg"]').attr('alt', gotVal);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('no name found.');
            }
        }
```